# Google Geocode api not returning postal_code for some 'direct hit' addresses

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

These don't seem to be `partial_matches` so I'm wondering why it's not bringing back all the data, specifically the `postal_code`.

From double checking on google maps, this is the exact address I want. In other words it's a direct hit.

Python code:

```
address = '34 new street, Green road, Carlow'

geocode_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}&key={}".format(address,api_key)

# Ping google for the reuslts:
results = requests.get(geocode_url)
# Results will be in JSON format - convert to dict using requests functionality
results = results.json()
```

And the results. There should be a `postal_code` data here, right? There's nothing to say that it was only a partial match.

```
{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '34',
     'short_name': '34',
     'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'New Street', 'short_name': 'New St', 'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Moanacurragh',
     'short_name': 'Moanacurragh',
     'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Carlow',
     'short_name': 'Carlow',
     'types': ['locality', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'County Carlow',
     'short_name': 'County Carlow',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Ireland',
     'short_name': 'IE',
     'types': ['country', 'political']}],
   'formatted_address': '34 New St, Moanacurragh, Carlow, Ireland',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 52.8296466, 'lng': -6.9331115},
    'location_type': 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 52.83099558029149,
      'lng': -6.931762519708498},
     'southwest': {'lat': 52.82829761970849, 'lng': -6.934460480291502}}},
   'place_id': 'EhozNCBOZXcgU3QsIENhcmxvdywgSXJlbGFuZCIaEhgKFAoSCZ93HqizQl1IEZZMDB0YIkdXECI',
   'types': ['street_address']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Now if I enter the exact same string into the official zipcode database (Ireland) it returns the zipcode.

Official database is [here](https://finder.eircode.ie/#/) by the way, you can try the address string `'34 new street, Green road, Carlow'`

Comment: This is interesting. I'd say perhaps Google just doesn't know the postal code, but viewing the address in maps - its definitely there!

Comment: What happens if you query by `place_id` instead of `address`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two points you should be aware regarding the sample request for '34 new street, Green road, Carlow'.

1. As you can see, the result has a `RANGE_INTERPOLATED` location type, not the `ROOFTOP`. That means Google doesn't have an exact address in their database and they tried to guess (interpolate) the position of the address based on other existing features.
2. If you execute the reverse geocoding request for the interpolated point (52.8296466,-6.9331115) and location type postal code `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.8296466%2C-6.9331115&result_type=postal_code&key=YOUR_API_KEY` you will get the following response

   { 
      "plus_code":{
          "compound_code":"R3H8+VQ Carlow, County Carlow, Ireland",
          "global_code":"9C4MR3H8+VQ"
      },
      "results":[
      ],
      "status":"ZERO_RESULTS"
   }

So, in Google database there is no postal code polygon that contains point (52.8296466,-6.9331115). You are facing a data issue on Google side.

I would suggest reaching out to the Google data team and report the data issue as described in their help center:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846

Hopefully Google can fix it soon.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately I have 100,000+ addresses to use with the api, so I can't update the maps info for every mistake I find. I'll just have to ignore these `range_interpolated` results when using the geocoder.

Comment: I just noticed I have this issue on Chrome vs. Safari.  Same long/lat coords sent for postal_code and Chrome returns zero results.  Safari comes back with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the coordinates to find the postal code, but first, find the coordinates using the address.

```
$apiKey = 'API_KEY';
$address = '&address=' . urlencode( $_POST['address'] )
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={$apiKey}{$address}";
$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);
// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

// get the important data
$lat = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] ?? "";
$lng = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] ?? "";
$cityCoce = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key{$apiKey}&latlng=$lat,$lng";
```